# Sheet not dismissing with presentation mode in SwiftUI/UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui, modalviewcontroller

I have a SwiftUI view that displays a sheet using a @State variable:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct AdRevenue: View {
    @State var playAd = false
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
            self.playAd = true
                    })
            {
                Text("Play Ad")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $playAd) {
                Ads()}
}
}
```

This is the UIViewRepresentable sheet:

```
  struct Ads: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController


func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    return ViewController()
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiView: UIViewController, context: Context) {
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADRewardedAdDelegate, AdManagerRewardDelegate {

var rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    AdManager.shared.loadAndShowRewardAd(AdIds.rewarded.rawValue, viewController: self)
    AdManager.shared.delegateReward = self    
    }


    func rewardedAd(_ rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd, userDidEarn reward: GADAdReward) {
      print("Reward received: \(reward.type), amount \(reward.amount).")
    }

}
}
```

Within AdManager, a function is called as such:

```
    func rewardAdDidClose() {

    let mom = Ads()

    mom.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    print("mom.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()")
}
```

Yet although I see the presentationMode message when I run it, the sheet doesn't get dismissed. Is it possible to dismiss the sheet like this?

Comment: try passing the presentation mode to Ad in sheet: `Ad().environment(\.presentationMode, self.presentationMode)`

Comment: @BokuWaTaka I get the error message: "Key path value type 'WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Binding<PresentationMode>>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Binding<PresentationMode>>'"

Answer (score 0):

Is this because you have two `Ads` values?

The first is created by SwiftUI (inside the `AdRevenue` view), so its `presentationMode` property is likely to be correctly wired-up to the app's environment.

But later, within `AdManager`, you're creating another `Ads` value, and expecting it to have a usable `presentationMode` environment object. It's being created outside of SwiftUI, so cannot know about the environment of the rest of your app.

I'd try passing the `Ads` value into your `AdManager`, rather than having `AdManager` create a new one.